# Arquillian embedded glassfish/payara runlevel annotation mismatch exception

Tags: maven, glassfish, jboss-arquillian, payara

I am trying to implement the beginnings of a test suite against a large code base that needs the CDI context for injection. I did have this working, but all of a sudden I started getting exceptions. Being new to Arquillian I followed the tutorial here: http://blog.payara.fish/testing-applications-with-payara-server-arquillian

My test class looks likes this

```
package test;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ArchivePaths;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.companyname.Customer;
import com.companyname.CustomerService;


public class InventoryServiceTest extends Arquillian {


 @Inject
CustomerService customerService;

@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).addPackages(true, "com.companyname")
            .addAsManifestResource("test-persistence.xml", ArchivePaths.create("persistence.xml"))
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));
}

@Test()
public void test() {

       List<Customer> customers = customerService.getCompanyCustomers("12");

       Assert.assertTrue(customers.size()>0);
   }
  }
```

and my pom.xml looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fish.payara</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-example</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ArquillianExample</name>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-testng-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.161</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

```
I'm running out of ideas at this ponint. It did work on a few occasions and then all of a sudden I started getting the stack trace below and I haven't been able to get rid of it. Thank you for any suggestions you may have!!!

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.9.10
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\ccrafton\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1369890448\testng-customsuite.xml

Dec 12, 2017 6:31:17 PM org.glassfish.security.services.impl.authorization.AuthorizationServiceImpl initialize
INFO: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Dec 12, 2017 6:31:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService createNetworkProxy
INFO: Network listener https-listener on port 0 disabled per domain.xml
Dec 12, 2017 6:31:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.AdminEndpointDecider setGuiContextRoot
INFO: Admin Console Adapter: context root: /admin
Dec 12, 2017 6:31:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.AdminEndpointDecider setGuiContextRoot
INFO: Admin Console Adapter: context root: /admin
Dec 12, 2017 6:31:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.AdminEndpointDecider setGuiContextRoot
INFO: Admin Console Adapter: context root: /admin
Dec 12, 2017 6:31:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup$MasterRunLevelListener onError
INFO: Shutdown requested
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scope name given in the descriptor (org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevel) did not match the scope annotation on the class (javax.inject.Singleton) in class MessageSecurityConfigEventListenerImpl
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:789)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:678)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:459)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:1986)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpAllTheWay.go(CurrentTaskFuture.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpAllTheWay.access$100(CurrentTaskFuture.java:443)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture.go(CurrentTaskFuture.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture.go(CurrentTaskFuture.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.proceedTo(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:436)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.RunLevelControllerImpl.proceedTo(RunLevelControllerImpl.java:71)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.proceedTo(AppServerStartup.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:228)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:219)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3_1.GlassFishContainer.start(GlassFishContainer.java:174)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:75)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian.arquillianBeforeSuite(Arquillian.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


Dec 12, 2017 6:31:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopServer doExecute
INFO: Server shutdown initiated
Dec 12, 2017 6:31:21 PM org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3_1.GlassFishContainer executeCommand
SEVERE: An unexpected exception occurred.
java.lang.RuntimeException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/deployment/interfaces/SecurityRoleMapperFactory
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.sun.enterprise.security.acl.RoleMapperFactory
    contracts={com.sun.enterprise.security.acl.RoleMapperFactory,org.glassfish.deployment.common.SecurityRoleMapperFactory}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.bootstrap.impl.Hk2LoaderPopulatorPostProcessor$1@320494b6
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=267
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=1315022947
    reified=false)

    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.preAuthorization(DeployCommand.java:311)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.CommandSecurityChecker$1.run(CommandSecurityChecker.java:187)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.CommandSecurityChecker$1.run(CommandSecurityChecker.java:183)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.util.CommandSecurityChecker.authorize(CommandSecurityChecker.java:183)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1239)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3_1.GlassFishContainer.deploy(GlassFishContainer.java:227)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian.arquillianBeforeClass(Arquillian.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with a later version of Payara? The latest is 4.1.2.174.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: I should note that the above works for a few tries and then all of a sudden eclipse starts failing with the above errors.

Comment: I've figured out that anytime I use a glassfish 4 embedded flavor then the runlevel complains. I could use glassfish 3, but I'm using java 8 and the app blows up.